# GNU make not working for simple test cases

Tags: makefile

First time posting on stackoverflow!

I'm just getting started on using GNU make. I'm using a simple example Makefile [described here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/) (and printed below). There are two steps to be completed by the Makefile, both of which I can complete without error without using make.

Here's the Makefile (truncated from original because I don't have topojson installed):

```
counties.zip:
    curl -o counties.zip 'http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip'

gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp: counties.zip
    unzip counties.zip
    touch gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
```

When I attempt to use make `make -f Makefile` or just `make`, I get the following:

```
curl -o counties.zip 'http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time      Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left      Speed
100 1277k  100 1277k    0     0   955k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:-    -:--  956k
```

The file successfully downloads, but is never unzipped in the next step. If I type `make` again, it prints:

```
make: `counties.zip' is up to date.
```

I've tried similar simple multi-step test cases and the same thing is happening - the first step is completed, but no subsequent steps are. I know I've installed programs using make in the past on this machine (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I've forgotten any relevant details or this is a redundant question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the rule at the beginning of the `Makefile`.

```
all: counties.zip gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.shp
```

Make sure [all](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) are the same, there is a good tutorial [here](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/), it is basic.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for linking to the tutorial too!